# Breaker Trips with No Load

Tags: electrical

I have a 30amp breaker that supplies a well pump in a detached shed that started tripping earlier this week. The wire is 10/2 UF direct burial and is likely original to the house (55 years old).

To troubleshoot, I have tried the following:

- Replacing the breaker (it was probably original).
- Replacing/tightening the wire nuts on the one splice I could find on this circuit
- Disconnecting the well pump entirely so there was absolutely no load on the circuit.

After each of the above steps, I reset the breaker, yet it would continue to trip after 10-60 minutes. I also did not observe any damage to the wires in any place I could see.

Are there any other troubleshooting steps that I can try? It seems to me that there is likely some underground damage and that this entire circuit needs to be replaced.

Comment: And this is why anyone with experience does NOT choose direct burial. Unless they are a fixed bid installer who does not plan to be available when it breaks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of:

- *10/2 UF direct burial and is likely original to the house (55 years old)*
- *I also did not observe any damage to the wires in any place I could see.*
- *trip after 10-60 minutes*

means a few things:

- Underground damage is quite plausible. Shouldn't happen with direct burial cable after a year. But 55 years is a different story.
- You don't have a dead short - that would trip right away. But you could have a high-resistance problem that results in somewhere between 30A and 40A. Which could easily happen if critters or corrosion have messed up the cable.

Read up a bit about *breaker trip curves* and you'll see that 30A doesn't mean "exactly 30A and never a drop over" but more like "30A for a long while, double that for a little while, triple that for a very short time".

One way to diagnose this a little more is with a clamp current meter on one of the wires right after breaker reset. If it shows 0A (or very low) then something else is going on, possibly an intermittent short. But if it shows 30A or more then that's your answer.

In either case - 30A+ flow due to a near-short, or an intermittent dead short - the answer will most likely be in that buried cable. Which means it is time to replace it. You can replace with similar cable and *probably* get a few decades of service from it, and then it will be someone else's problem. Or you can install conduit. A lot depends on distance (conduit + wires will cost more than cable) and digging (direct burial cable has to go deeper than conduit, and conduit depth depends on conduit type to some degree). If you have use for additional electric power at the pump location besides the pump itself then conduit makes sense as it allows for expansion. If not, then it is a question of the various costs involved (conduit/wire vs. cable, labor for digging).

Comment: I reset the breaker and used a clamp meter on each leg of the circuit. I observed 0A on both for the few minutes that I tested.

Comment: Interesting. Did you leave it on long enough for the breaker to trip? Not sure how it would from 0A to 30+A. I could easily see it going from a few A to 30+A if there was a bad connection that heated up until it got worse and tripped the breaker.

Comment: No, I monitored it for about 5min and it was at 0A the whole time. It tripped about 15min after I stopped.

Comment: So there are two possibilities: between 5 & 15 minutes it gradually ramped up to be enough to trip, *or* it is an intermittent dead short and happened to hit at 15 minute mark.

Comment: Is there any practical difference in how I would address one vs the other? Sounds like in either case I would be looking for damage that I can't find because it's probably underground.

Comment: Agreed. Shovel time

Comment: ...and use conduit when you get the new trench dug.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect the wires from the breaker.

If that solves it the problem is likely a break or damage you aren't aware of. Somewhere there's a short to neutral or ground.

If you want further confirmation, place a power consumption measuring device on the circuit.